# Internationalization - Generate/auto-translate .arb files tools

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization

I have an .arb file in my Flutter project to handle Internationalization

```
{
  "@@locale": "en",
  "play": "Play",
  "@play": {
    "description": "Text displayed on the landing page play button"
  },
  "howToPlay": "How to Play",
  "@howToPlay": {
    "description": "Text displayed on the landing page how to play button"
  }
}
```

I'd like to auto-generate/auto-translate this .arb file in other language as the process of manually editing is quite long in VsCode

Are there any tools for this or flutter/dart packages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[localizely_sdk: ^2.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/localizely_sdk)
or any other "Over The Air" (OTA) service for translate